# Implement common methods in two angular js controllers to open common html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on AngularJS application, in which I need to show common popup on creating an item. The popup will be same for all application, but the implementation of method of save and close will be different in each of calling controller.

Below is the code of common html page :

**saveItem.html**

```
  <div class="modal-header">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.closeItem()" style="color: #061530;font-size: 25px;float: right;" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
            ng-click="vm.createItem()">Create another item
    </button></div>
```

I used ngDialog to open common page. Below code is used to open the html page :

**FirstController** and **SecondController** :

```
ngDialog.open({
                      template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
                      scope: $scope,
                      showClose: false
                   });
```

What I want ?

I want different implementation of `createItem()` and `closeItem()` methods in FirstController and SecondController.

But when I implementing both methods in-

**FirstController :**

```
function closeItem() {
           ngDialog.close();
         }

 function createdItem() {
          //implemtation on FirstController
         }
```

In **SecondController**

```
function closeItem() {
               ngDialog.close();
             }

    function createdItem() {
              //implemtation on SecondController
             }
```

But it working in FirstController only. How can I write different implementation in both controllers?

Also is there any way to preserve previous state with ngDialog?

Comment: `//implemtation on FirstController, go to page 1'  is it a implementation to go to page 1 ???? 

quite confused!

Comment: This is just implementation of FirstController that is different from the SecondController.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for `ngDialog`, you can specify the controller you want to use for the dialog:

> Controller that will be used for the dialog window if necessary. The
>   controller can be specified either by referring it by name or directly
>   inline.

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'externalTemplate.html',
    controller: 'SomeController' });
```

One way is to load different controllers for each situation:

```
function openFirstDialog() {
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
    scope: $scope,
    showClose: false,
    controller: 'FirstController'
  });
}

function openSecondDialog() {
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
    scope: $scope,
    showClose: false,
    controller: 'SecondController'
  });
}
```

Another solution would be to use a `$scope` variable to decide the action:

```
function openFirstDialog() {
  $scope.firstController = true;
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
    scope: $scope,
    showClose: false
  });
}

function openSecondDialog() {
  $scope.firstController = false;
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
    scope: $scope,
    showClose: false
  });
}
```

Then check the `$scope` variables in your dialog controller:

```
function closeItem() {
  ngDialog.close();
}

function createdItem() {
  if($scope.firstController) {
    //implemtation on FirstController, go to page 1
  }
  else {
    //implemtation on SecondController, go to page 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Both approaches, I have tried but not working. Created different dialog controller, but still not calling the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Add the methods to the scope that you provide for the dialog:

```
$scope.closeItem = function() { ngDialog.close(); }
$scope.createdItem = function() { // do whatever }

ngDialog.open({
                      template: 'app/confirmation/saveItem.html',
                      scope: $scope,
                      showClose: false
                   });
```

Comment: Using scope does not calling any method, I am trying in same controller like in FirstController. But it is not working.

Comment: Maybe post some code showing how the dialog is calling those methods?  If they're events you're expecting to get called automatically, we may need to try something different